# Adding Image to JPanel directly

Tags: java, swing

I'm working on a project to design a game and I was wondering if it's possible to add an image to the JPanel directly without adding it to jLabel and then add the label to the panel.

Comment: It is possible, but why don't you want to use a `JLabel`?

Comment: you only really have 2 options: Should the image in another component like JLabel or paint it directly in paintComponent

Comment: Because I'm new to java and I want to use drag and drop later so I don't know if I add an image to a label and then add the label to the panel will have any effects on the drag and drop functionality or if it will cause any other problems. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Drag-and-dropping of images is quite easy with JLabels. Consider reconsidering use of JLabel here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try like this:

```
class Sample extends JPanel {
    BufferedImage image;

    Pseudo(BufferedImage image) {
        this.image = image;
        // or load it in this class
        setLayout(null);

    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int x =
        int y =
        g.drawImage(image, x, y, this);
    }
}
```

This will add image directly to JPanel.